# Jasmine spyOn testing functionality with faked return array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

The function I am trying to test with Jasmine fetches an array of objects, then uses the `splice()` method to reorder it in accordance with the function's passed parameters.

I understand I use `spyOn().and.returnValue()` to fake the return array. But how do I test the reording functionality of the function using that fake return? In particular how do I reference the faked return in the spec?

Note: after the reordering, other functions are called. I want to capture the results of the reorder before it continues.

```
function templates($rootScope, $q) {
    return {
        reorder: function(item, fromIndex, toIndex) {
            var storeDeferred = $q.defer();
            $rootScope.store.templates.all(function(templates) {
                if (templates) {
                    // Reorder templates
                    templates.splice(fromIndex, 1);
                    templates.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
                    // Nuke then insert back reordered
                    this.nuke(function() {
                        this.batch(templates, function(templates) {
                            storeDeferred.resolve(templates);
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    storeDeferred.reject('templates not found');
                }
            });
            return storeDeferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
describe('Unit: templates', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
        inject(function($injector) {...}); // inject Templates and $rootScope
    });

    describe('Templates.reorder', function() {
        it('should move object at index 2 to the start', function() {
            spyOn(rootScope.store.templates, 'all').and.returnValue([{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a:3}]);
            Templates.reorder({a:3}, 2, 0);
            expect(REFERENCE_THE_FAKE_RETURN).toBe([{a:3}, {a: 1}, {a: 2}]);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the all function to accept a callback and then call the callback with the array you need to test with. You then need to use a variable to store the templates that get passed into the promise that is returned. After that you need to call $digest() and then you can then compare the values using `angular.equals`. In order to mock `this` for unit testing, you can use the `bind` function that will set `this` to a mock.

```
describe('Templates.reorder', function() {
    it('should move object at index 2 to the start', function() {
        var templatesFromPromise;
        rootScope.store = {
            templates: {
                all: function(callback) {
                    var thisMock = {
                      nuke: function (nukeCallback) {
                          var nukeCallbackBound = nukeCallback.bind(thisMock);

                          nukeCallbackBound();
                      },
                      batch: function (data, batchCallback) {
                          batchCallback(data);
                      } 
                    };

                    var callbackBound = callback.bind(thisMock);

                    callbackBound([{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]);
                }
            }
        };

        spyOn(rootScope.store.templates, 'all').and.callThrough();
        Templates.reorder({a:3}, 2, 0).then(function (data) {
            templatesFromPromise = data;
        });

        rootScope.$digest();

        expect(angular.equals(templatesFromPromise, [{a:3}, {a: 1}, {a: 2}])).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kJl8nN7GIeOMP9eRJzrU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The test is now complaining about the `nuke()` function that comes after, that it is undefined. Do I then place a spy on that function? If so how do I reference the fact that it is called with `this`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to set up a Plunkr? I had a hard time testing the code so I had to improvise.

Comment: Here's the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gNIOBewedG37dL7VPgTA?p=preview) with your solution added - failing on the `nuke()` function.

Comment: I can see that it works correctly in your plunkr. However, when implemented in my code I get error: `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'callback.bind(thisMock)')`. Even copying the entire `describe` block produces that error. Do you understand how it could work in plunkr but not in my own environment?

Comment: What's in your environment? Are you using Karma?

Comment: Yes it's Karma - would that affect it?